# getting all attribute value using textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

my xml look like this:

```
<oneday>
      <team1 id="1" team="India">
           <team2 id="2" team="gujarat">
                  <team3 id="3" team="guj11"></team3>
           </team2>
      </team1>
</oneday>
```

this is my code what i done?:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var xml;
$.get(
    "cricket.xml",  
    function(data) { xml=data; },
    "html"
);
function get_list(){

    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $title = $xml.find($("#select").val());
    $("#result").html($title.text());
}
</script>
</head>
<input type="text" id="select">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Search" onclick="get_list()" >
<div id="result">
</div>
</html>
```

i want to output:
if i entered in text box India then display Gujarat and guj11
entered Gujarat then output is Guj11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the input item like below:

```
$title = $xml.find('[team="'+$('#select').val()+'"]');
```

and then find his children use :

```
$nodes = $title.find('*');
```

Here is my new `get_list` function:

```
function get_list(){
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $title = $xml.find('[team="'+$('#select').val()+'"]');
  $nodes = $title.find('*');
  var result='';
  $nodes.each(function(){
    result += $(this).attr('team');
    result += ' ';
  });
  $("#result").html(result);
}
```

jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/g9mYk/

Answer (score 0):

```
$title = $xml.find($("#select").val());
```

you are finding the value of '#select' in your $xml object. it is wrong

you can parse your xml like this..

```
$team1 = $(xmlDoc).find("team1");
alert($team1.attr("id"));
alert($team1.attr("team"));
```

Comment: its good work but not exactly i need... i need something like this enter in textbox India then give the output Gujarat and Guj11... fetch child and sub child attr value...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function get_list(){
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $title = $xml.find('[team="'+$('#select').val()+'"] *');
    var str='';
    $title.each(function(){
        str+=$(this).attr('team')+' ';
    });
    $("#result").html(str);
}
```

Also you can change your xml for your convenience like

```
<oneday>
      <team id="1" team="India">Test
           <team id="2" team="gujarat">
                  <team id="3" team="guj11">Hello</team>
           </team>
      </team>
</oneday>
```

as there is id defined for each tag team1, team2, team3.